# Qemu static configure error (thread local storage)

Tags: arm, fedora, configure, qemu

I'm trying to compile Qemu for this target in a static way : {arm-linux-user, armeb-linux-user, arm-softmmu}.

here is this configure command I'm using :

```
./configure --target-list="arm-linux-user armeb-linux-user arm-softmmu" --disable-werror --enable-debug --static
```

When I'm executing this command I got the following error :

> C++ compiler c++ does not work with C compiler cc Disabling C++
>   specific optional code
>
> ERROR: Your compiler does not support the __thread specifier for 
>          Thread-Local Storage (TLS). Please upgrade to a version that does.

Or, my cc version is 5.1.1 so this is quite new :

```
[lionel@localhost qemu]$ cc -v
Utilisation des specs internes.
COLLECT_GCC=cc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.1.1/lto-wrapper
Cible : x86_64-redhat-linux
Configuré avec: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada,go,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl --enable-libmpx --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.1.1 20150618 (Red Hat 5.1.1-4) (GCC)
```

I can compile it normally without the "--static" argument. I need to compile it in static way as I am trying to chroot into a filesystem where binaries are ELF arm executable..

If it is not possible I could possibly use `qemu-system-arm` to emulate to board.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that you have `g++` installed?

Comment: I'm not sure why configure is complaining about the TLS support, but using --static is really only properly supported for building the linux-user binaries (arm-linux-user, armeb-linux-user, etc). Try configuring and building the linux-user binaries only statically (--target-list="arm-linux-user armeb-linux-user" --disable-tools --static) in their own build directory. Then build the arm-softmmu binary (if you need it) non-statically in a second builddir (--target-list="arm-softmmu").

Comment: ok thanks, will check that later, thanks for your reply. I succeeded to get static version of qemu few weeks ago via the repository of my linux distro, but I will give a shot at you solution.

Answer (score 0):

Configure will also produce this error message if your linker is broken (ie trying to compile a .c program to an executable doesn't work), because the TLS check happens to be the first one which tries to do that -- in this case it will print a misleading error message. In this case your compiler is definitely new enough to handle __thread, so you should check whether your linker works OK. Looking in config.log will show all the programs QEMU's configure script tried to run and their output.

(I just submitted a patch -- http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/548123/ -- which will result in a less confusing warning if your linker doesn't work.)